# I have an image that has a hover effect, but there is a text above and it avoids it

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to put a text on top of an image, but if I pass the cursor over the text, my image is not animated. how can I do so that when the cursor is over the text, even if the image is animated, try to act as if the text were not there.

how can do it?

```
    const svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width",1000).attr("height",1000);


    var widthMarker=50;

    var imgContainer = svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(228,53)");

    var img = imgContainer.append("svg:image")
    .attr("xlink:href", "marker.svg")
    .attr("width", widthMarker)
    .attr("height", widthMarker)
    .attr("x", 228)
    .attr("y", 50)
    .on('mouseover', function() {
      d3.select(this)
        .transition()
        .ease("bounce")
        .duration(500)
        .attr("height", widthMarker + 50)
        .attr("y", 17);
    })
    .on('mouseout', function() {
      d3.select(this)
        .transition()
        .ease("bounce")
        .duration(500)
        .attr("height", widthMarker)
        .attr("y", 50);
    })
    var text = imgContainer.append("svg:text")
      .attr("dy", widthMarker/2)
      .text("hello world");

    text.attr("dx", (widthMarker - text.node().getComputedTextLength()) / 2)
      .attr("transform", "translate(228,53)");
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/MfNlziZCJJXFbwfx3t4w?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pointer-events: none`

`text.attr("pointer-events", "none");`